# Hibernate bulk update leads to in-query which takes for ever to complete

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

`Article` entity is a sub-class of the `Product` entity. The inheritance strategy for them is `joined`. `Article#flag` is a boolean attribute which I want to set false for all articles. Hence, I do

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("update Article set flag=:flagValue");
query.setParameter("flagValue", false);
query.executeUpdate();
```

I expected this to lead to a single SQL statement against the database which should complete fairly quickly. Instead Hibernate populates a temporary table (which does not physically exist in the database) and runs an in-query ie. the update later:

```
insert into HT_article select article0_.id as id from schema.article article0_ inner join schema.product article0_1_ on article0_.id=article0_1_.id

update schema.article set flag=0 where (id) IN (select id from HT_article)
```

The actual update statement takes "forever" to complete and locks the affected articles thereby causing lock exceptions in other transactions. By forever I mean more than an hour for 130000 articles.

What's the explanation for this behavior and how could I solve it? Other than running a native query I mean...

**Update 2011-05-12:** it's terribly slow because the in-query is slow, I filed a bug for that -> http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5905

Comment: It's worth mentioning that also `Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(
        "update Article set flag=false where articleNumber in (:articleNumbers)");
    query.setParameter("articleNumbers", articleNumbers);` leads to the same terribly slow processing using the HT_article table.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `InheritanceType.JOINED` of hibernate and faced a similar issue where hibernate was inserting into the temp table and was taking ages to delete the entities. I was using `createQuery` and `executeUpdate` to delete the records which caused the issue.
Started using `session.delete(entity)` which solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using `InheritanceType.JOINED`, Hibernate has no choice but to unify the subclass and its base class.

If you switched to `InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS` (http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/jpa_overview_mapping_inher.html) you'd avoid this and get your performance back. But I'm sure you're using `JOINED` for a reason :-(

Comment: I don't understand this claim. If the 'flag' is a member of Article (the sub class) and not of Product why would Hibernate have to unify the classes?
Btw, back in Decemeber I started http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/hibernate-dev/2010-December/005873.html. One of the responses points to http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/MultitableBulkOperations and http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/BulkOperations which explain what might be going on behind the scenes.